# Structs and interface types

Tags: go

Could someone please explain (or if it's a long thing to explain at least point me to some documentation) why this code is behaving like it does. It's a bit lengthy but I couldn't figure out a good way of shortening it without losing too much info.

What confuses me is that I need to have the method "Find" on each type of struct for it to be recognized as the type it is. With Find on only the baseTypeImp is it printing that each is baseTypeImp, if I have it on baseTypeImp and advancedBaseTypeImp are those two identified correctly, but not the last type.

[PlaygroundLink](https://play.golang.org/p/k62WRW5rqgC)

**My Code**

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "reflect"
)

type BaseType interface {
    Name() string
    Find(string) BaseType
    Children() []BaseType
    Options()
}

type baseTypeImp struct {
    name     string
    children []BaseType
}

func (b baseTypeImp) Options() {
    fmt.Println("Not implemented")
}

func (b baseTypeImp) Find(name string) BaseType {
    if b.name == name {
        return b
    }

    for _, c := range b.children {
        if m := c.Find(name); m != nil {
            return m
        }
    }
    return nil
}

func (b baseTypeImp) Name() string {
    return b.name
}
func (b baseTypeImp) Children() []BaseType {
    return b.children
}

type AdvancedBaseType interface {
    Value()
}

type advancedBaseTypeImp struct {
    baseTypeImp
}

func (a advancedBaseTypeImp) Options() {
    fmt.Println("Is implemented")
}

func (a advancedBaseTypeImp) Value() {
    fmt.Println("Value called")
}

func (a advancedBaseTypeImp) Find(name string) BaseType {
    if a.name == name {
        return a
    }

    for _, c := range a.children {
        if m := c.Find(name); m != nil {
            return m
        }
    }
    return nil
}

type reallyAdvancedBaseTypeImp advancedBaseTypeImp

func newThingy(name, variant string, children []BaseType) BaseType {
    base := baseTypeImp{name: name, children: children}
    switch variant {
    case "advanced":
        return advancedBaseTypeImp{baseTypeImp: base}
    case "reallyAdvanced":
        return reallyAdvancedBaseTypeImp{baseTypeImp: base}
    }
    return base
}

func whatType(b BaseType) {
    if b == nil {
        return
    }
    fooType := reflect.TypeOf(b)
    fmt.Println(b.Name(), " is type ", fooType.Name())
    b.Options()
}

func main() {
    advanced := make([]BaseType, 0, 5)
    for i := 0; i < 5; i++ {
        advanced = append(advanced, newThingy(fmt.Sprintf("Advanced %d", i), "advanced", nil))
    }
    reallyAdvanced := make([]BaseType, 0, 2)
    for i := 0; i < 2; i++ {
        reallyAdvanced = append(reallyAdvanced, newThingy(fmt.Sprintf("ReallyAdvanced %d", i), "reallyAdvanced", advanced[i:i+3]))
    }
    basic := newThingy("Basic parent", "basic", reallyAdvanced)
    whatType(basic.Find("Basic parent"))
    for i := 0; i < 2; i++ {
        whatType(basic.Find(fmt.Sprintf("Advanced %d", i)))
        whatType(basic.Find(fmt.Sprintf("ReallyAdvanced %d", i)))
    }
}
```

**The output now is:**

```
Basic parent  is type  baseTypeImp
Not implemented
Advanced 0  is type  advancedBaseTypeImp
Is implemented
ReallyAdvanced 0  is type  baseTypeImp
Not implemented
Advanced 1  is type  advancedBaseTypeImp
Is implemented
ReallyAdvanced 1  is type  baseTypeImp
Not implemented
```

**What I'd like to have is:**

```
Basic parent  is type  baseTypeImp
Not implemented
Advanced 0  is type  advancedBaseTypeImp
Is implemented
ReallyAdvanced 0  is type  reallyAdvancedBaseTypeImp
Is implemented
Advanced 1  is type  advancedBaseTypeImp
Is implemented
ReallyAdvanced 1  is type  reallyAdvancedBaseTypeImp
Is implemented
```

Is there a way to get this working without having to implement Find on each level? It kind of defeats the purpose of having the common methods in the top layer struct. And of course, if possible explain why it's behaving the way it does.

Comment: You're thinking about it in the opposite way, if you allow me to use your vocabulary, it is not the *top* layer, it is actually the *bottom* layer. And methods can "see" only from their own layer down, the upper layers are not accessible to a method call.

Comment: Note also that, when you **embed** a type in a [struct](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Struct_types) as you're doing with `baseTypeImp`, the members (fields and methods) of the embedded type get **promoted** to the embedding type. "Promoted" members can be accessed directly, i.e. without spelling out the embedded field, however they have no knowledge of the embedding type, the one in the above layer.

Comment: There are no type hierarchies or inheritance in Go; and embedding **is not** a way to emulate type hierarchies or inheritance. It seems like you're trying to "fake" an OOP-style hierarchy in Go using embedding. It will not work.

Comment: @Adrian no, it's not trying to "fake" an OOP-style hierarchy. It's a tree of interfaces and I wanted to be able to find nodes (of different types) by name starting at any point in the tree. I'm not trying to emulate inheritance, it's just that all these types have a lot in common and the code (which I'm not the author of) uses embedding. Burak kindly explained why that isn't possible the way I thought it would be, so I'll be on my way trying to figure out a working way

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you embed a struct into another one, the outer struct gets the methods of the embedded one.

```
type inner struct {
}

func (i inner) f() {}

type outer struct {
  inner
}
...

x:=outer{}
x.f()
```

You can think of this as syntactic sugar for:

```
type outer2 struct {
  i inner
}

y.i.f()
```

When you embed `inner` without a field name, you simply drop the `i` in the call. You can still call `x.inner.f()` in the first example.

When you redefine a type, it does not get the methods defined for its base type.

```
type newtype inner
```

`newtype` does not have `f()` defined. However, if `inner` also embeds other structs (like you do), then those are still embedded in the new type, so those function are defined:

```
type deepest struct {}
func (deepest) deep() {}

type inner struct{}
func (inner) in() {}

type outer inner
```

Above, the type `outer` does not have the function `in`, but it has `deep`.

So when you call `reallyAdvancedBaseTypeImp.Find()`, what you're really doing is `reallyAdvancedBaseTypeImp.baseTypeImp.Find()`, which works on that portion of the struct. That's why you're getting the types you get.

You're trying to emulate method overriding. You can't really do that. Formulate your problem in a different way.

Comment: Thanks for a very good explanation! So, in a case such as mine I'd have to either redefine the same Find on each struct, or have a function Find which traverses the whole tree? It's hard to explain all the nitty gritty details as it's inherited code using a 3rd party c library so I don't have too much wiggle room. Basically it's a bunch of widgets with different behaviour, but some in common, and I guess this is a try to come around the (very) hard typing of Go.

Comment: Solution depends on the exact case. If all `Find`s are different, then you'd need a `Find` on each struct, but if they're the same, you can find a good grouping. One way is to implement a common `Find` function (not a method), and have methods delegating to it.